# what does the error message "[[: not found" mean

Tags: bash

I am debugging a bash shell script, and I am getting this error message:

[[: not found

The line number it points to is the end of my outer do loop.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit:  here is the script:  https://github.com/stephenh/git-central/blob/master/server/post-receive-hudson

Comment: Could you provide the sample code to see the error in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[[` is used in BASH as a builtin test condition. However, it doesn't work in regular Bourne shell that many systems default to when running things like cronjobs, etc.

Are you putting the shebang (`#! /bin/bash`) as the first line of your shell scripts? Is this a cronjob? Can you print out the value of `$RANDOM` (Bash will print out a value, Bourne will not)?

Show us the program that's giving you this problem, and tell us about the system it's running on (Linux? Solaris? Intel? Cygwin?) maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks!! changing to shebang fixed the problem.